# systemd Restart is not working?

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, raspbian, services

I have the following service.

/etc/systemd/system/detectwifi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=wifi detect automation
Requires=wpa_supplicant.service
After=wpa_supplicant.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I started the service, I have seen that the command `wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B` is running. Then killed the process and it won't restart again.

May I know the reason why the restart is not working?

Also If I comment the line `RemainAfterExit=yes`, then the service will start to restart but it keeps on restart continuously even if the process run successfully.

Comment: You might want to try `Type=forking` since you start `wpa_cli` in daemon mode.

Answer (score 1):

A recommedation to keep `-B` and switch to a readiness protocol that the program does not speak is another example of why one should always take comment-answers with a huge dose of salt.

- Do not use `RemainAfterExit=yes` when it is a lie, as here.  Your dæmon *is not* considered running when the process has exited.
- Do not use `-B`.  The idea of dæmonization is a fallacy in any case, and your process *is already running* in a dæmon context.

One problem that you will encounter is that systemd does not know that your service should not be run until the relevant `wpa_supplicant` service has bound its control socket in `/run/wpa_supplicant/`.  There are timing problems here that people just have to bodge around with things restarting continually until the service "takes".

`wpa_supplicant` does not yet provide a way for its control socket to be passed in as an already open file descriptor, which would allow it to be defined using a systemd socket unit, which the `wpa_cli` service unit could then be ordered after.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  [*Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).   Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*You really don't need to daemonize. Really.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The systemd House of Horror.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- Chiraag Nataraj (2019).  *[Minimalistic Wireless Networking With systemd](https://chiraag.nataraj.us/wireless/index.php)*.  chiraag.nataraj.us.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401611/5132